# checking unique while inserting to mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-collection

I have a program to insert some values into the mongo db and i want to avoid repeated product_src inserting into the database. how can i set that in code? my code is

```
BObject doc = new BasicDBObject("product_name", bean.getProductName()).
                    append("product_url", bean.getProductURL()).
                    append("product_img", bean.getImageURL()).
                    append("product_price", bean.getPrice()).
                    append("product_src", bean.product_src).
                    append("country", bean.country));
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check first given value exist or not in mongoDB collection.

Comment: thats what i want but how can i do that using mongoDB

Comment: .append("unique", true).

will appending this will do ?

Comment: @praveen_programmer no it will not avoid duplicates. It will add a field with the name unique and the value true to all documents. There are no magic values to set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to ensure the uniqueness of product_src:

- Store it  as the documents `_id`. There is always a unique index constraint on _id
- [Create a unique index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) on product_src

With a unique index MongoDB will throw an error when inserting a document with a duplicate value and not add the document to the collection.

Comment: so can i catch the error and continue the process ?

Comment: Yes, I can't remember the exact details on how to catch atm., but it is easy to test.

Comment: @sarath how could you do that finaly after 6 years :)?

Answer (score 1):

After much research I found unique check without raising duplicate Error.

```
db.collection("collection_name")
    .updateOne({ field1:"field1", field2:"field2" }, {
        $setOnInsert: { _id: "ObjectID" }
    }, {
        upsert: true
    })
```

The above query will insert only if document not found.
If document found then the response will be as shown below.

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: null,
  upsertedCount: 0,
  matchedCount: 1
}
```

If document not found then response will be as shown below.

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedId: 'some_upserted_id',
  upsertedCount: 1,
  matchedCount: 0
}
```

To summarize my research, if we have

> upsertedCount: 1 or upsertedId: 'some_upserted_id'

then record inserted successfully else document already exist and we don't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; a uniqueness check without error is just what I needed.